# ConcurrentHashMap values become empty

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

I have two classes one of which implements runnable, this one gets the data from a website then puts it into a ConcurrentHashMap and the other gets this data later. First class successfully gets the data and puts it into the map, I can see the map is full but when the other class tries to get data, keys are here but values become empty.

```
public class KAuctionThread extends KObject implements Runnable 
{
...
    KParserMapBaseClass.getLiveStreamMap( this.getThreadConfig( ).getDataSource( ) ).put( realTimeActionKey, di ) ;
...
}
```

This line puts the data into the map below

```
public abstract class KParserMapBaseClass extends KObject implements Callable<KDownloadInfo>
{
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo>> liveStream = new ConcurrentHashMap<>( ) ;// !!!
...
...
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> getLiveStreamMap( String dataSource )
{
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> dataSourceMap = KParserMapBaseClass.liveStream.get( dataSource ) ;

    if( dataSourceMap == null )
    {
        dataSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo>( ) ;

        KParserMapBaseClass.liveStream.put( dataSource, dataSourceMap ) ;
    }

    return dataSourceMap ;
}
}
```

I can see the data in eclipse expression when first class puts it:

```
{B2BOtoNet={someurl=com.lib1k.cmap.agent2.KDownloadInfo@622d2710}}
```

But when the other class tries to reach

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> map = KParserMapBaseClass.getLiveStreamMap( di.dataSource ) ;
    if( map != null && map.size( ) > 0 )
    {
        String key = map.keySet( ).iterator( ).next( ) ;

        KDownloadInfo rtdi = map.remove( key ) ;

        return rtdi ;
    }
```

Map becomes like that:

```
{B2BOtoNet={}}
```

There is no other class that puts or gets the data

Comment: Do you mean to use `remove` instead of `get`? (Also you are using `ConcurrentMap` with sequences of operations, instead of making use of the atomic operations.)

Comment: I want a processed data to be removed, is there any disadvantages of using remove? I will try a more atomic implementation

Comment: Why use a Map if you're not using the keys? It seems you're just getting the first key before removing it. A `List` would be more efficient for that use case. Besides, Maps usually don't guarantee the order of keys (except `LinkedHashMap`).

Comment: Make your static method `getLiveStreamMap()` `synchronized` and tell us if it's working.

Comment: I tried making it synchronized but nothing changed. In another piece of code I use keys to get values

Comment: Then I would explicitly `synchronize` all accesses to your "Map of Maps" and all its Maps, print a statement *after* the synchronized block and see what goes wrong...

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to say without a reproducible example. It could be that this method is not atomic and that you are overriding instances in the map that have already been created before.

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> getLiveStreamMap(String dataSource)
{
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> dataSourceMap = KParserMapBaseClass.liveStream.get(dataSource) ;

    if (dataSourceMap == null)
    {
        dataSourceMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo>();
        KParserMapBaseClass.liveStream.put(dataSource, dataSourceMap);
    }
    return dataSourceMap;
}
```

You can do the same thing more concisely and atomically:

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, KDownloadInfo> getLiveStreamMap(String dataSource)
{
    return liveStream.computeIfAbsent(dataSource, k -> new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
}
```

Comment: I think I do not override any object because when I go back to first class in debug, the objects are still here.

Comment: It's perfectly possible that it's a race condition that will not be reproducible when you start introducing breakpoints and therefore stop-the-world events. The above is *certainly* a bug. Whether it is *the exact* bug that is causing your problem is impossible to say given we cannot reproduce the problem. You should fix it regardless.